# How to get Year View in full calendar control

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar control v1.6.4. Is there any way to get year view with fullcalendar control?
I tried something like this but the year option is not coming.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {            
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'year,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
```

Thanks

Comment: I think, that's impossible!:)

Comment: if it's impossible then what could be the easy way to let the users select a future date in next two years. In case if there is a recurring meeting. Just wondering if FullCalendar gives any easy option or just move month by month to future years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not have a Year view because it doesn´t exist, as you can see in the [Available views](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/).

But if you want to allow the user to move to another year without clicking every month, as you suggest in your comments, you can attach to the form a datepicker, and get the result of the user selection.

You could use, for example, [jqueryUi datePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and detect when its changed using [onSelect event](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect). Then, you just need to change the date of your fullCalendar.

So you could have something like:

```
$(".date").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
       var selectedDate = this.value;
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', selectedDate );
  }
});
```

Comment: this looks like a perfect solution for my problem. I am implementing this. I just wanted to confirm about the Year view option in FullCalendar before adding a datepicker. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: You're welcome Ramee. I had the same problem and that's what I'm using.

Comment: Cool but I feel FullCalendar should consider this option. We are now forced to add one more control just for future date selection.

Comment: There's already an open and accepted issue, requesting this, that you can follow here: https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=225